# Player Sprite Doesn't Move (Unity, C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I was attempting to make a top down 2D shooter using Unity. My code contains no errors that I could see, RigidBody2D and PlayerMovement (code for the player to move) have been added to the sprite, and RigidBody2D has been added to the PlayerMovement. My move speed is set to 5. Please let me know what I can do to fix this issue!

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    Vector2 movement;

    void Update()
    {
        MovementInput();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = movement * moveSpeed;
    }
    
    void MovementInput()
    {
        float mx = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float my = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        
        movement = new Vector2(mx, my).normalized;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to move the character with the mouse?

Comment: I am! If you know anything about it, please share your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Use your character sprite as the mouse cursor instead to write a code to make the player follow the mouse pos

If you really want to move your player via script this video will help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Qy3l3VuF_o

Have a good day :)

Answer (score -1):

Check if your rigidbody2D's Body type is set to static, If it is then set it to kinematic or dynamic.

Also where did you import the script to?

Your code is not the problem, I tested it myself! Although you could move MovementInput(); to the FixedUpdate. Its not required though.

Edit: [Image of the inspector as i have it if it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMp4b.png)

Comment: My Rigidbody2D is not set to static. I imported the script into the "rb" segment of my PlayerMovement code, once it was added.

Comment: I added a picture of what I have if it helps. ( I have no idea whats going on )